# Firebase functions not working with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const axios = require('axios')

exports.getTown = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${data.lat},${data.lng}&result_type=locality&key=**********`)
    .then(town => {
        return town
    }).catch(err => {
        return err
    })


})
```

When I call this in the front end I just get an error in the console:

```
POST https://europe-west2-heretic-hearts.cloudfunctions.net/getTown 500
Uncaught (in promise) Error: INTERNAL
```

I've tested to make sure the incoming data is being received properly and it is, so the problem must be in the function itself. But I can't see what could possibly be going wrong here...?

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke an onCall type function with a simple POST request.  [Callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) have a [specific protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) that they use on top of HTTP.  If you can't reproduce that protocol, the function will fail every time.

If you want to write a simple HTTP function endpoint, then follow the instruction for writing an [HTTP trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) instead using onRequest.  It works very differently.

Also, I'm noticing that you're not handling promises correctly in your function.  Please *read the documentation thoroughly* to understand what you need to do with promises in order to get your function to execute correctly, no matter what type of function you write.